# ¿Cómo usar un paquete que no tiene su versión en TypeScript en un proyecto de React JS (que usa TypeScript)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Estoy creando un proyecto en React JS y TypeScript, quiero usar el paquete [react-zoom-pan-pinch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-zoom-pan-pinch), el cual instalé con `yarn add react-zoom-pan-pinch`. Al importar el paquete recibo el siguiente error:

> Cannot find module 'react-zoom-pan-pinch' or its corresponding type declarations.

En base a lo que leí en Google tengo que ejecutar el siguiente comando `yarn add @types/react-zoom-pan-pinch`, pero al ejecutarlo recibo el siguente error:

> An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@types%2freact-zoom-pan-pinch: Not found".

Lo que me lleva a pensar que este paquete no tiene una versión en TypeScript, mi pregunta es: cómo puedo usar este paquete en mi proyecto?

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes la oportunidad de actualizar TypeScript, hazlo, porque por lo que recuerdo no debería ser necesaria una librería de types en nuevas versiones, al menos creando una app de prueba usando typescript 3.7.5 no me da ningún problema al importar la librería que mencionas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De todas formas, en la raiz de tu proyecto, crea un archivo `externals.d.ts` y agrégale:

```
declare module "react-zoom-pan-pinch";
```

Que en el fondo es como definir una declaración de types vacía para la librería.